# MAUI: Release build directly crashes on Android device

Tags: android, maui

I built a .NET MAUI project and want to install this on my local device (Android 9). When i start directly out of VisualStudio as Debug build everything works well. When i change build type to Release, the splash screen is visible for a second and after that, the app closed directly.

I have no clue what the problem is. Is there an opportunity to debug release build or have a log view, why the app crashes instantly?

Thank you and best regards!

Comment: Look at the device logs

Comment: Have you looked at the logcat output? It's available from within Visual Studio. Are you using any features requiring special permissions?

Comment: Thank you! When I have a look into the device logs, it seems like there are different problems:
**1)** _java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider microsoft.maui.essentials.fileProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "microsoft.maui.essentials.fileProvider" on path: DexPathList_
**2)** _No package ID ff found for ID 0xffffffff_
**3)** _Could not find icon drawable from resource_

Why does this work in debug build and not in Release build? What can I do to avoid this errors? Thank you!!

Comment: OK, got it! There was an automatically edited area in the AndroidManifest adding and linking the microsoft.maui.essentials.fileProvider DLL. I removed this area and now it works. Thank you!